# All connections insecure, unable to connect over WiFi except for Google-hosted web sites - possible causes?

Tags: wi-fi, browser

Recently I have been having this issue and it has become a real pain that is almost constant.

I can use Google Search, YouTube etc. in the web browser (Chrome and Firefox). However if I try to access anything else I get that it's unreachable. The thing is the web sites (notice the plural form!) are all reachable and I can access them if I switch to LTE instead of using the WiFi connection at home. In addition I have also noticed that all the pages are **insecure connection**, which should not be the case. Last but not least I can enter web sites (not hosted by Google) via the app that shows stories (news snippets - can be accessed on a Moto G by swiping left to right when in home screen), which is powered by Chrome.

The web sites are all secure and with my laptop (WiFi) I have no issues accessing them and viewing the certificate information.

I tried flushing the DNS host cache via `chrome://net-internals/#DNS` but nothing changed. I don't see any indication of incorrect system time. I'm out of ideas.

The issue was "solved" by modifying the WiFi connection and setting it to static IP address along with a manually entered gateway and DNS. I don't mind adding my phone as a static IP in my router but I would **rather know how this situation occurred so that I prevent it repeating on other devices**. In the end there is a solution that goes around the problem and a solution that solves the actual problem. I am interested in the latter.

Comment: Congratulations on solving your own problem. However, this post corrupts the Q&A form of this StackExchange, where Qs and As are separate posts. Please feel to submit an answer to your own question by editing out the update into its separate post. You will also get the opportunity to ACCEPT and gain reputation that way too.

Comment: Since this only happens on WiFi, I'm afraid there's a possibility of the ISP doing MitM (see also this question on Security.SE: [Can ISP use MITM attack to "break" encrypted traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/64352/59741)). I also faced this issue sometimes on with my mobile data provider where they inject ads on non-HTTPS sites. [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking) might also be related.

Comment: @wbogacz I will paraphrase the question so that it concentrates more on why this is happening.

Comment: @AndrewT. I might run a malware scan on my phone. When it comes to apps I am pretty hermit-like - I spend a lot of time choosing the app so that I don't have to change it later. As for the ISP being at fault here while I do not like Vodafone (my ISP in Germany) and the router they provided me with is utter garbage the fact that both both my and my partner's notebook and also her iPhone don't encounter this issue I am more willing to lean towards malware on my Android.